# What's the meaning of idiom 'one less thing'?

Tags: idioms

What's the meaning of "one less thing" in the following sentence.

> That's one less thing you'll have to think about in launching a
>   business.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When you launch a business you have to think about many things—a long list of things.

Every time you encounter a new problem, you add it to the list. The list is longer by one, and you have ***one thing more*** or ***one more thing*** to think about. And

Each time you are able to cross something off that list, the list grows shorter by one. That’s ***one thing less*** or ***one less thing*** you have to think about.

Answer (score 0):

I think it means: 
That you have lots of things to think about in launching a business; and this is one of those many things that you don't have to think about.
*PS---(I am not a teacher nor an expert, so don't really count on that answer).

Answer (score 0):

> That's *one less thing* you'll have to think about in launching a business.

Means:

You don't have to think about that thing when launching a business. It's probably already done,  or something not to be done at all, so you don't have to think about it anymore.